# Algorithm for order of operations in math

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing, math, matrix

I'm having issues with **implementing an order of math operations** rule in my code.
I have 2 arrays. Array of matrices (up to 100 matrices) and array of operations (up to 99 operations). The operations are only addition, substraction and multiplication of matrices (represented by + - *).

My matrices are a structure, but that's just a detail. I have working functions for everything regarding them.

I also have a function for executing the operations.

```
struct Matrix compute(struct Matrix mat1, struct Matrix mat2, char op)
```

The function has a switch, which determines the operation and executes the correct one.

The piece of code I need to improve is this one.

```
// counter = number of matrices in the array
// therefore there's also counter-1 operations

struct Matrix temp = compute(matrices[0], matrices[1], operations[0]);
for(int j = 1; j < counter; ++j)
{
    temp = compute(temp, matrices[j+1], operations[j]);
}
get_matrix(temp); //outputs the matrix to stdout
```

At the moment, this code evaluates correctly all sequences of matrices and operations that do not include multiplication (supposing the input was correct and operations can be executed).

**What do I need?** I need a kick in the butt in the right direction.

Comment: Are you saying that you need a way to enforce order of operations on an expression where operands are matrices? And currently it fails for multiplication e.g. `1+2+4*0` evaluates to `0` if the operands where numbers?

Comment: @Miket25 Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. Also apparently there's a memory leak in this part of code (matrices are dynamically allocated), though Im freeing the temp matrix just 2 lines under the shown code. But that's an issue I can solve later.

Comment: Research building **abstract syntax trees**. Nodes within this tree will be matrices and operands. You then recursively evaulate this tree, which will achieve order of operations. I recommend **recursive descent parsing**; it's easy to learn. You can fine good examples online on order of operation calculators through recursive descent parsing and apply it to this problem.

Comment: Is that right that there are no parentheses in your sequence of operations? Only operation priority must be enforced, right?

Comment: @Miket25 I will research that, thank you! It's difficult for me to name my problem since I'm not a native.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No parentheses whatsoever, the array of operations is just a string of +-* (f.e. +++*---+-***+)

Comment: The [Shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is effective and easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach is to walk through the sequence of matrices once, and execute only multiplications. Create a new sequence composed of matrices after multiplications have been applied. For example, if the initial sequence is like this

```
|A| * |B| + |C| * |D| * |E| - |F| + |G| * |H|
```

the sequence after processing multiplications would look like this:

```
|A*B| + |C*D*E| - |F| + |G*H|
```

This would remove all multiplications from the sequence, bringing you to a problem that you already know how to solve.

**Note:** Your code has an off-by-one error: when `j` is equal to `counter`, `matrices[j+1]` references an element one past the end of `matrices[]` array.

You can fix this by checking that `j+1 < counter` inside the loop. Another approach is to copy `matrices[0]` into `temp`, instead of performing the initial operation out-of-bound. This way you can starts `j` at zero, to make sure that the code works even for the "degenerate" case of a single matrix.

Comment: Thank you, the first memory solution did the trick, there's not a memory leak anymore, therefore only the original problem remains - the order of the operations :)

Comment: Also - that's a clever idea, how did I not think about that. I think I'll try to implement that first before researching the solutions suggested above.

Comment: @Welsy Abstract syntax trees would be needed if you had parentheses. Since your case is so straightforward, the simple multiply-first solution should work.

Comment: Hey, Im having issues again. I had to change a few things and there's leaks again. But they only appear if there's 3 or more matrices. I would be very grateful if you helped me.
https://i.imgur.com/S3Y2atV.png

Comment: I did valgrind --leak-check=full but it points to that temp = compute.. line.I sadly don't know what exactly isn't beeing freed. I only know its in that line.

Comment: Inside. If you look at the imgur link, the code there - the compute function is only called in the loop.

Comment: I am probably giving up. It’s 3:30am, the homework is due at 9am. I’ve done the part I had to (only 2 matrices and 1 operation). This is a bonus part for extra points. I can’t figure out how to prevent the leak and I still havent implemented the multiplication priority. The whole code is about 400 lines. I can’t give you 400 lines of code to read, that would be insane haha. Thanks for the effort tho.

Comment: @Welsy `temp = compute(temp, ...)` leaks the previous `temp`. You need to make a copy of `matrix[0]` before entering the loop, then compute `temp2 = compute(temp, ...)`, then `free(temp)` and finally assign `temp = temp2`.

Comment: Does it? And is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I mean I havent given up yet, but Im out of ideas.

Comment: NO LEAKS!!! Man, I owe you so much. I now have about 5 hours to implement the priority. I'll do my best not to waste your advice!